# Display traffic data with maps

Tags: maps, leaflet, traffic

I am trying to show traffic information on OpenStreetMap. Considering that the traffic information is a value from 0 to 3 (which means bad, regular and free) and also consider that value is changing in a certain frequency.

Does anyone has a suggestion to make this work?
Maybe drawing polylines in the map, I prefer to stay simple.
My application uses Leaflet maps and node.js

Comment: You can see an example of WightedPolyline on Leaflet-DVF project http://humangeo.github.io/leaflet-dvf/examples/html/runmap.html